# Docker push to artifact registry using docker-dind on gitlab-runner kubernetes executor on gcloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, google-artifact-registry

I am running a gitlab-runner with kubernetes executor in gcloud. I have it configured with TLS and I can run the docker commands just fine.

But when it comes to the `docker push` it fails with the following

`denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource ...`

My gitlab-yaml looks something like this

```
image: docker:20.10.16

services:
  - name: docker:20.10.16-dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
  DOCKER_CERT_PATH: "$DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR/client"

stages:
  - build
    
build:
  stage: build
  services:
  - docker:20.10.16-dind

  variables:
    TAG: v${CI_PIPELINE_IID}
  script:
    - docker build -t imagename:${TAG} job/
    - docker tag imagename:${TAG} imagename:latest
    - docker push europe-docker.pkg.dev/project/repository/imagename:${TAG}
```

I tried to add a new service account and add it to the gitlab yaml, I gave the service account permission to use the artifact registry, but with no luck.

```
variables:
  KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OVERWRITE: ci-service-account
```

Then I tried to use gcloud to do the auth as following in my gitlab-yaml

```
 - apk add --update python3 curl which bash
 - curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
 - export PATH=$PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin
 - gcloud auth configure-docker europe-docker.pkg.dev
```

It runs and finishes but still gives the same error.

Any pointer on where to go, would be most welcomed! Thank you

Comment: Has your issue been resolved? I am happy to help in case of any queries.

Comment: @FariyaRahmat It has not been resolved. I keep getting this error `unauthorized: failed authentication`. 
I used docker-credentials-gcr v2.1.6, and tried granting project-wide permission. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Is this the same error as you have mentioned `denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource`  or some other error you are facing now? Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Github](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/pull/1255) link:

> Update the docker-credential-gcr helper to v2.0.1  if you are using a
> lower version to support authenticating with GCP's Artifact Registry.

Also there are some points to have a consideration regarding permissions

**Granting [project-wide](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#grant-project) permissions**

Grant a role at the project level if the same permissions apply to all repositories in the project. add a team member to a project and grant them an Artifact Registry role.

**Granting [repository specific](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#grant-repo) permissions**

Grant repository-level permissions when you want users or service accounts to have different levels of access for each repository in your project.

Additionally you can see this link on  [Configuring IAM roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#roles) .